# JavaRMI connection to localhost failure

Tags: java, rmi

I´m starting with RMI.

I wan´t to create a server in Java for a database manger (Is a college thing) and when I run the code listed below, to start the interface for the server, i have a connexion failure with localhost:

By the way, Im Using OS X and Eclipse to code.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package es.uned.database;

import es.uned.common.IBasededatos;
import es.uned.common.Utils;

import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.*;

import es.uned.common.IServidor;

/**
 *  
 * @author 
 * 
 */
public class Basededatos extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IBasededatos{
    protected Basededatos() throws RemoteException {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Utils.setCodeBase(IServidor.class); 


        if (System.getSecurityManager()==null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }
        String nombre = "//localhost/Basededatos";
        try{
            IBasededatos servidorBD = new Basededatos();
            Naming.rebind(nombre, servidorBD);
            System.out.println("Data base is up an ready");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Database exception: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the error message I get.

access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")

I´ve tried this other code, but with the same success

```
/**
 * 
 */
package es.uned.database;

import es.uned.common.IBasededatos;
import es.uned.common.Utils;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.*;

/**
 *  
 * @author 
 * 
 */
public class Basededatos implements IBasededatos{
    public Basededatos()  {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Utils.setCodeBase(IServidor.class);   


        if (System.getSecurityManager()==null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }
        String nombre = "//localhost/Basededatos";
        try{
            IBasededatos servidorBD = new Basededatos();
            IBasededatos stub = (IBasededatos)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(servidorBD, 1099);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.rebind(nombre, servidorBD);
            System.out.println("Servidor Base de datos arriba");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Excepcion base de datos: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Can anybody help me? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The client is getting the Registry from the wrong place. The Registry it needs to lookup is at the server host, not its own localhost.
2. RMI URLs are for use with the Naming class. You're using the Registry interface in the client so you shouldn't be specifying `//localhost/` at all.